# Emmet plugin's expansion doesn't work for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I successfully installed Emmet via Package Control.

- When I type `ul` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get `<ul></ul>`.
- When I type `ul.class` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get `ul.body_class` but I want it to generate `<ul class="class"></ul>`.

What am I doing wrong?

I have read posts saying to try <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> as the trigger key, but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 8):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> instead. If that doesn't work, you can try changing the keybinding by putting the following in your User key bindings file which can be found by doing *Preferences -> Key Bindings — User*:

```
[
    {"keys": ["tab"], "args": {"action": "expand_abbreviation"}, "command": "run_emmet_action", "context": [{"key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"}]}
]
```

and then just change `"tab"` to whatever keybinding you want. Check to see if that works.

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> did nothing, so I edited my Key Bindings as suggested, but that didn't help. If I type `ul.class` + `Tab` it just tabs over to the right with no code expansion at all.  
Here is my User Key Bindings content:  
`[
 { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+f"], "command": "reindent" },
 { "keys": ["tab"], "args": {"action": "expand_abbreviation"}, "command": "run_emmet_action", "context": [{"key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"}] }
]
`

Answer (score 3):

After reading your question, I installed Emmet in the Windows version of Sublime Text 3 today and had the same problem.  Within my search for the solution, I found the following:

http://docs.emmet.io/actions/expand-abbreviation/#comment-1272517661

In Windows I opened the Default Emmet Preferences.  By going to:

Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Setting - Default
and
Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Key Bindings - Default

As I was closing the settings files, I was prompted to save the setting files.  I clicked OK to save and then restarted Sublime Text 3.

After Sublime Text 3 reloaded:
I created a new html file and was able to type `ul.class`, tabbed and it expanded to `<ul class></ul>`

It was funny, I never ran into that problem with Sublime on my Mac.  If you had to do the same process on Mac, you go to Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet ...

Comment: Strange. When I go to Preferences > Package Settings from there my only option is Package Control. I do see Emmet settings as an option to edit.

Also, when I open any of the other settings files, I am not prompted to save them unless I have made a change.

Comment: Are you sure Emmet was installed correctly? Can you open up the command panel with Ctrl+Shift+P and do `Package Control: List Packages` and make sure Emmet is listed?

Comment: Have you tried removing emmet in sublime, restarting sublime, and then running the install procedure again?  Also, what platform? Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: All I did, following reading this, was go to my Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Keybindings User (and also the default, but it wouldn't let me save the default) and typed one space to effect a change, saved, restarted ST3 and it's back to working!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. Just pasted the below code in "Preferences -> Key Bindings — User:".

```js
{
  "keys": ["tab"], 
  "command": "expand_abbreviation_by_tab", 

  // put comma-separated syntax selectors for which 
  // you want to expandEmmet abbreviations into "operand" key 
  // instead of SCOPE_SELECTOR.
  // Examples: source.js, text.html - source
  "context": [
    {
      "operand": "SCOPE_SELECTOR", 
      "operator": "equal", 
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "selector"
    }, 

    // run only if there's no selected text
    {
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "selection_empty"
    },

    // don't work if there are active tabstops
    {
      "operator": "equal", 
      "operand": false, 
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "has_next_field"
    }, 

    // don't work if completion popup is visible and you
    // want to insert completion with Tab. If you want to
    // expand Emmet with Tab even if popup is visible -- 
    // remove this section
    {
      "operand": false, 
      "operator": "equal", 
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "auto_complete_visible"
    }, 
    {
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "is_abbreviation"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Github: See for more description](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#how-to-expand-abbreviations-with-tab-in-other-syntaxes)

Answer (score 1):

I check the emmet default key is `ctrl+e`, so I add this to my `Key Bindings -  User`:

```
{"keys": ["tab"], "args": {"action": "expand_abbreviation"}, "command": "run_emmet_action", "context": [{"key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will have shared this as a comment directly where I feel like but 50 reps was required. Any ways. Here is what I did that made mine work for me.

From @saadq's answer, do this: 
[
//other user key bindings should be here, followed by

```
{"keys": ["tab"], "args": {"action": "expand_abbreviation"}, "command": "run_emmet_action", "context": [{"key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"}]}
```

]

The point is to have other bindings appear before it so that whatever binding overwriting it will be overwritten again.